# Swapping 2 string pointers with a function whose parameters are void **

Tags: c, pointers

The following code doesn't compile:

```
void swap(void **p, void **q) {
  void *tmp;
  tmp = *p;
  *p = *q;
  *q = tmp;
}

int main(void) {
  char *s[] = {"help" , "please"};
  swap(&s[0], &s[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

While this code compiles and runs just fine:

```
void swap(void **p, void **q) {
  void *tmp;
  tmp = *p;
  *p = *q;
  *q = tmp;
}

int main(void) {
  char *s[] = {"help" , "please"};
  swap((void **) &s[0], (void **) &s[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Why is the casting necessary ?

Comment: A `char **` is not the same as a `void**`.

Comment: Because a pointer to `void*` is not universal with a pointer to any other pointer type (like a pointer to `char*`). A `void**` is a pointer to a specific type: `void*`.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html

Comment: @WhozCraig your one line explanation is very nice. and I realized my answer is incomplete (actually incorrect answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, so in addition to the already existing answers that point out that `void **` is not the same as `char **`: your code invokes **undefined behavior** because of the incompatible pointer types. Here's what you actually want:

```
void swap(void *p1, void *p2, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char buf[size];
    memcpy(buf, p1, size);
    memcpy(p1, p2, size);
    memcpy(p2, buf, size);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
const char *s[] = { "help", "please" }; // also note the use of `const' for string literals
swap(&s[0], &s[1], sizeof(s[0]));
```

Comment: I deleted my answer (I feel not properly answer the issue). I also feel you should explain WhozCraig's  point for OP .

Comment: +1 for seeing not only the problem with the code, but seeing problem the OP was trying to *solve*. I wish I could up-vote it a second time for pointing out the undefined behavior.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan your answer wasn't wrong, and in fact it may be the "answer" that H2C03 refers to as "existing answers" in his opening comment. Your third and fourth paragraphs are essentially what my comment was about: pointer type incompatibility. Undelete it and I'll up-vote it. It should be here as well. H2C03's answer drives home the UB nature of what the OP was trying, but your answer should be in the list.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yeah, ^^ that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks man!..Actually the line `void* can be assigned any address type but its void** that has to be assigned address of void* type variable.` I added after reading you comment. When I notice that H2CO3 posted a nice answer So I wanted him to explain your comments too (what I was explaining).

Comment: OK I undelete answer so it can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You have incompatible pointer assignment error in first code. In C type of a string literal is `char[N]` Where N is number of chars. Note in most of expressions `char[N]` easily decays into `char*`

According to your  declaration `char *s[] = {"help" , "please"};`  type of `s[i]` is `char*` (actaully `char[N]` decayed into `char*`).

When you pass `&s[i]` then you are passing `char**` that is incompatible with `void**`. Second code works because you typecast into `void**` in function calling.

`void*` can be assigned any address type but its `void**` that has to be assigned address of `void*` type variable.

If you only having array of strings then in first version of swap function you can replace `void` by `char` then you can all without typecast.

Answer (score 0):

The casting makes the example compile because of what you are passing the function.

`char *var[];` is in many ways the same as `char **var;`

With that being said, you are passing the function a reference/address one of the members of the array (`s[0]`).

Another more prominent issue, is that the function accepts void pointers, and is passed character pointers (without the casting).

Comment: The function as the OP declared it doesn't accept void pointers; it accepts *pointers* to void pointers. They are *not* the same (though one can, in fact, pass a pointer to a void pointer to a function that takes a void pointer as a parameter).

Comment: right, I was also trying not to get confused in the area of pointer to pointers vs pointer arrays vs pointer to pointer arrays etc... The list goes on...