# int fun(void **args) and on calling of function pass the argument fun(args),

Tags: c++, c

I am using some inbuilt function `fun(void **args)` and to call this function passing argument `fun(args);` so what is mean of `void **args` and how to check what does value `args` have in C.

```
void GetValues(void ** args, nsString sToken, int iTokenNo)
{  
    printf("Token is : %s and Token no is %d ",sToken,iTokenNo);
    NSLog("Token Name %s and Token no is %d",sToken,iTokenNo);
}
```

On calling of this function i have to pass `GetValue(args,TokenName,TokenNo);` i think it is now clear what i want to ask. why i have to pass args and even i am not using the value of `void**args` .

Comment: `void **` pointer to pointer

Comment: Read a good book on C programming (and then another good book on C++11 programming, they are different languages). Perhaps `fun` is called like `fun(&p);` where `p` is declared `void*p;`

Comment: Read [Swapping 2 string pointers with a function whose parameters are `void **`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340892/swapping-2-string-pointers-with-a-function-whose-parameters-are-void)

Comment: i know it is pointer but thing is that i am using an IDE where this is built in function int fun(void **); if we have to call this function i have to use fun(args); but i never user the value of args in function , i do not write this void** it shows error.

Comment: @user2652114 Note: `void*` can be assigned any address type but its `void**` that has to be assigned address of `void*` type variable.

Comment: It would help if you told us what the function is supposed to do, and show how you are trying to call it.

Comment: How is args declared before it is used to call GetValues?

Answer (score 2):

args is a pointer to a pointer to some data (could be anything, it would be cast to the right int, char, struct or whatever inside fun().

You can check the value of args itself, it will be a memory location, that points to another memory location that points to "something".

Note that args itself cannot be changed inside fun because C only passes arguments by value, but the pointer it points to can be changed...

If that does not make sense, you should study more C.

Comment: void GetValues(void ** args, nsString sToken, int iTokenNo)
{ 
printf("Token is : %s and Token no is %d ",sToken,iTokenNo); NSLog("Token Name %s and Token no is %d",sToken,iTokenNo);
}   on calling of this function i have to pass GetValue(args,TokenName,TokenNo); i think it is now clear what i want to ask. why i have to pass args and even i am not using the value of void**args .

Comment: move this comment to your question